# Is this real scenario using boost::asio for full duplex communication?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

I'm using [boost::asio](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/doc/html/boost_asio.html) library for creating full duplex server. I wondering whether this situation is possible to happen.

1. Came a request which is stored in its own buffer.
2. I filled the response data in its own buffer.
3. I'm starting to send the response asynchronously.
4. Came a new request.
5. I filled the response data in the same buffer in which I had filled it previous time.
6. The buffer of the previous write operation which is not yet finished is corrupted with the new response data.

The question is whether I need separate buffer for every write operation or in point 3 the buffer is copied in some kind of internal buffer and I can safely to fill the new response in the same buffer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

boost::asio is able to do full-duplex operation, but you should manage buffers carefully.

The general rules is:

1. Only 1 read operation on given socket can be active at a time.
2. Same for write operations

So you can do 1 write and 1 read operation simultaneously.

Situation you described should work in single-threaded environment since process cannot add to buffer and use it for write simultaneously. But, there is a trick however: after you append to write buffer you cannot know is current async_write done or not. Do you need to start new async_write or not? This moment needs to be carefully verified.

P.S. And no, asio never copies buffers internally.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean with *"Situation you described should work in single-threaded environment since process cannot add to buffer and use it for write simultaneously."*? The situation which I described is exactly the situation in which I write to the buffer when there is started asynchronous write.

Comment: Can you propose some method for detecting whether there is ongoing *async_write* operation when I'm ready to start the next *async_write* and for starting the next *async_write* in the right moment when the previous is finished?

Comment: In single thread situation when async_write started, and you appending data to buffer, your process doing only 1 job at the moment, not both. So there is no race conditions on buffer. On 2nd question: i'd do a flag, indicating async_write is in process (and reset flag when its handler is called)

Comment: I'm not appending to the buffer but I'm writing again from it's beginning and because of this I think that the data needed for the previous write will be overwritten. Strictly technically speaking there may not have race condition, but I think that the described by me use is still incorrect, and I think that the correct way of doing this is to have a queue of buffers for each asynchronous write.

Thank you for your answer, especially for emphasizing me to be careful to not start the next asynchronous write before I'm sure that the previous one is finished.